# How do XamlReader.Read or XamlReader.Parse instantiate types in order to build the wpf tree?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I know that for controls with specified `clr-namespace:` and `assembly=` tokens, XamlReader just looks for that type in the specified assembly.

But what about default WPF controls in the default namespace `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`?

I'm trying to get the **Type** of each element in an XElement tree, but I don't know how to find it when no assembly is specified?

For example, all of the following examples return null:

- `Type.GetType("Grid")`
- `typeof(Control).Assembly.GetType("Grid")`
- `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Control)).GetType("Grid")`

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To duplicate the behavior of `XamlReader`, you can use a `XamlSchemaContext` to perform the lookup of the type. For details, refer to [Default XAML Schema Context and WPF XAML Schema Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633576%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

The [`GetXamlType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474971(v=vs.110).aspx) method allows you to pass a Xaml Namespace and type name:

```
var context = new XamlSchemaContext();
var xtype = context.GetXamlType(new XamlTypeName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "Grid"));
var gridType = xtype.UnderlyingType;
// gridType == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Grid)
```

Note that this technique also works when there is a namespace, which allows you to have a single unified mechanism to parse your Xaml resources.

Comment: what about replicating it trying to find attached properties?

Comment: Not sure @Maslow - I'm no longer using this anymore for anything, but know this does fail for a few things (like some resources).